# Is Firefox technically correct in function hoisting within if statements with latest ECMA?

Tags: javascript, hoisting, ecma262

I learned that the following does not work in FF and does in every other standard browser.

```
if(jQuery){
    importantScript();

    function importantScript(){
        console.log("this is important");
    };
}
```

This is because FF does not hoist functions within if statements. It sounds like this used to be a rule, but I was reading [page 533 (B.3.3)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) and B.3.4 here are the cliff notes :

> Prior to ECMAScript 2015, the ECMAScript specification did not define
>   the occurrence of a FunctionDeclaration as an element of a Block
>   statement’s StatementList. However, support for that form of
>   FunctionDeclaration was an allowable extension and most browser-hosted
>   ECMAScript implementations permitted them. Unfortunately, the
>   semantics of such declarations differ among those implementations.
>   Because of these semantic differences, existing web ECMAScript code
>   that uses Block level function declarations is only portable among
>   browser implementation if the usage only depends upon the semantic
>   intersection of all of the browser implementations for such
>   declarations. The following are the use cases that fall within that
>   intersection semantics:
>
> 1. A function is declared and only referenced within a single block
> 2. A function is declared and possibly used within a single Block but also referenced by an inner function definition that is not contained
>      within that same Block.
> 3. A function is declared and possibly used within a single block but also referenced within subsequent blocks

Can you help me interpret this? I feel that the code above would meet the technical rules described above.

Comment: Function hoisting in blocks is a *new* rule in ES6, one that some versions of FF did not yet implement. They eventually will.